# counting and summing data from the nested array

Tags: php, arrays, json

So what I'm trying to achieve is sum and sort data to nested array.

So let's say i recieve results in this format:

```
{
    "resources": "[{\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"brand_id\": \"1\", \"quantity\": 3}]",
    "reportable_id": 1,
}
{
    "resources": "[{\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"brand_id\": \"1\", \"quantity\": 2}]",
    "reportable_id": 1,
}
{
    "resources": "[{\"name\": \"Product 2\", \"brand_id\": \"2\", \"quantity\": 2}]",
    "reportable_id": 7,
}
{
    "resources": "[{\"name\": \"Product 6\", \"brand_id\": \"8\", \"quantity\": 2}]",
    "reportable_id": 7,
}
{
    "resources": "[{\"name\": \"Product 3\", \"brand_id\": \"3\", \"quantity\": 3}]",
    "reportable_id": 4,
}
{
    "resources": "[{\"name\": \"Product 3\", \"brand_id\": \"3\", \"quantity\": 3}]",
    "reportable_id": 4,
}
```

And the results should be:

```
"1": {
    {
        name: Product 1,
        brand_id: 1,
        quantity: 5 // see we sum the data of all products with the same brand_id in the reportable ids.
    }
}
"7": {
    {
        name: Product 2,
        brand_id: 2,
        quantity: 2
    },
    {
        name: Product 6,
        brand_id: 8,
        quantity: 2
    }
}
"4": {
    {
        name: Product 3,
        brand_id: 3,
        quantity: 6
    }
}
```

Basically I can achieve this if i leave out the reportable_id, which I can't leave out.
What would be the correct way of doing this?
This is what i got so far, and it isn't it, because the summing and placing the items into the correct array indexes is not exactly how it should be:

```
function sortObjects($objects)
{
    $data = []; 
    $product_ids = [];
    $device_data = [];

    foreach($objects as $object) {

        $encoded_data = json_decode($object['resources'], true);
        $reportable_id = json_decode($object['reportable_id'], true);
        foreach($encoded_data as $key => $endoresment) {

            $data[$encoded_data[$key]['brand_id']]['name'] = $encoded_data[$key]['name'];
            $data[$encoded_data[$key]['brand_id']]['brand_id'] = $encoded_data[$key]['brand_id'];
            if (!in_array($encoded_data[$key]['brand_id'], $product_ids)) {
                $product_ids[] = $encoded_data[$key]['brand_id'];
                $data[$encoded_data[$key]['brand_id']]['quantity'] = $encoded_data[$key]['quantity'];
            } else {
                $data[$encoded_data[$key]['brand_id']]['quantity'] += $encoded_data[$key]['quantity'];
            }
            $device_data[$reportable_id] = $data;
        }

    }
    return $device_data;
}
```

The data will be returned as php array.

Comment: I suppose you do realise that your _should be_ result is not valid Json or anything else as far as I can see

Comment: No, the results are returned as an array, but the data i recieve is json.

Comment: Anyone knows what would be the propper way? Still not solved.